# É recomendável usar typedef em C++?

Tags: c, c++, sintaxe, estilo-de-codificação, typedef

Eu sei que C++ tem compatibilidade com C, mas C++ tem seu jeito de programar e C também, e por isso há coisas legadas do C que não devem ser usadas em C++, o `typedef` é uma delas? Se sim, o que usar no lugar do `typedef` quando se programa em C++?

Comment: `typedef` é compatível com `c++` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `typedef` é uma das coisas do C que não se usa muito em C++, mas depende da situação.

A definição de uma `struct` já é *typedefed* (toda definição de estrutura composta já é um tipo definido no código) pelo C++ automaticamente, então não tem porque usar nessa situação, ainda que seja aceito por compatibilidade. O mesmo vale para construções novas da linguagem que se assemelham.

E para criar um *alias* de tipo é recomendado a adoção do [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) no lugar do `typedef`, pelo menos em quase todas situações. Essa é uma forma mais moderna e melhor.

Comment: Como assim "typedefed"? É tipo, se eu escrever "struct minha_struct ms;" é igual a "minha_struct ms;"? É isso "typedefed"?

Comment: é isso mesmo...